# FTP 550 ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable on IIS7.5

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5

At a customer project: they get the 550 FTP error code (ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable) when performing the LIST and NLST command. Has anybody seen this before?

Server info:

It runs in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.
In IIS log I found the sc-win32-status code: 1236 (the network connection was aborted by the local system) and the sc-win32-status code: 4294967295 (max connection setting in IIS).
Basic authentication is ON and they use No SSL certificate

Client info:
They use Filezilla to connect to FTP server